# How to read and format a stream of text received through a bash pipe?

Tags: bash, go, npm, stream, pipe

Currently, I'm using the following to format data from my npm script.

```bash
npm run startWin | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done | less
```

It works, but my colleagues do not use Linux. So, I would like to implement `while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%b\n' "$line"; done` in Go, and use the binary in the pipe.

```bash
npm run startWin | magical-go-formater
```

#### What I tried

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
  fi, _ := os.Stdin.Stat() // get the FileInfo struct

  if (fi.Mode() & os.ModeCharDevice) == 0 {

    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
    str := string(bytes)
    arr := strings.Fields(str)

    for _, v := range arr {
      fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Currently the program silences any output from the text-stream.

Comment: If the only use of this program is to process stdin, why are you trying to get the fd mode at all? (there are cross platform packages to detect a tty if that’s what you need) Just read stdin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [bufio.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) for tail-type reads.  IMHO the checks you're doing on `os.Stdin` are unnecessary, but YMMV.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914003/reading-input-from-stdin-in-golang) for an example.  `ioutil.ReadAll()` (now deprecated, just use `io.ReadAll()`) reads up to an error/EOF, but it is not a looping input - that's why you want `bufio.Scanner.Scan()`.

Also - `%b` will convert any escape sequence in the text - e.g. any `\n` in a passed line will be rendered as a newline - do you need that?  B/c go does not have an equivalent format specifier, AFAIK.

**EDIT**

So I think that, your `ReadAll()`-based approach would/could have worked...eventually.  I am guessing that you were expecting behavior like you get with `bufio.Scanner` - the receiving process handles bytes as they are written (it's actually a polling operation - see [the standard library source for `Scan()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.5:src/bufio/scan.go;l=135) to see the grimy details).

But `ReadAll()` buffers everything read and doesn't return until it finally gets either an error or an EOF.  I hacked up an instrumented version of `ReadAll()` (this is an exact copy of the standard library source with just a little bit of additional instrumentation output), and you can see that it's reading as the bytes are written, but it just doesn't return and yield the contents until the writing process is finished, at which time it closes its end of the pipe (its open filehandle), which generates the EOF:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // os.Stdin.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))

    b, err := readAll(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: ", err.Error())
    }

    str := string(b)
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func readAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, 0, 512)
    i := 0
    for {
        if len(b) == cap(b) {
            // Add more capacity (let append pick how much).
            b = append(b, 0)[:len(b)]
        }
        n, err := r.Read(b[len(b):cap(b)])

        //fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "READ %d - RECEIVED: \n%s\n", i, string(b[len(b):cap(b)]))
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s READ %d - RECEIVED %d BYTES\n", time.Now(), i, n)
        i++

        b = b[:len(b)+n]
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "RECEIVED EOF")
                err = nil
            }
            return b, err
        }
    }
}
```

I just hacked up a cheap script to generate the input, simulating something long-running and writing only at periodic intervals, how I'd imagine npm is behaving in your case:

```
#!/bin/sh

for x in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
  cat ./main.go
  sleep 10
done
```

As a side note, I find reading the actual standard library code really helpful...or at least interesting in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

@Sandy Cash was helpful in stating to use `Bufio`. I don't know why, if what @Jim said is true, but `Bufio` worked out and `ReadAll()` didn't.

Thanks for the help.

#### **The code:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        s := scanner.Text()
        arr := strings.Split(s, `\n`)
        for _, v := range arr {
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're still splitting on `\n` which won't exist within individual lines

Comment: @PedroGomesBranquinhoFacti - the `Scanner` is tokenizing the input on `\n` - this is why the lines won't contain any newline characters.  Just remove the call to `strings.Split()` and do whatever you want to do with the value returned from `scanner.Text()`, no need to range over a slice here.

Comment: Note the use of the raw string literal in the answer (I missed it on my first reading of the answer). 
 The program translates `"\r\n"` and `"\\\n"` to `"\n"`.

Comment: It has been working since the day I compiled it. Why are you commenting on stuff not working?